# Userform command button to delete selected row stopped working - getting errors when attempting to fix

Tags: vb.net, userform, commandbutton

When I debug it, it appears to be matching the Shop Order Number correctly, but it still deletes the first row in the worksheet, which is above the table. The table headers are in row 3 the databodyrange starts in row 4.

```
'Delete Button code 2 Not working
Private Sub cmbDelete_Click()
If MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbYesNo + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2, "Delete this order") = vbYes Then

    Dim son As String
    son = Trim(txtShopOrdNum)
    Dim orderTable As ListObject
    Set orderTable = Worksheets("MASTER").ListObjects("MASTER")
    Dim matchRow
    matchRow = Application.Match(son, orderTable.ListColumns("SHOP ORDER NUMBER").DataBodyRange, 0)
    Rows(matchRow).Delete
    MsgBox ("Shop Order deleted.")
Else
    MsgBox "Deletion canceled."
'do nothing
End If

Dim ctrl As Variant
For Each ctrl In Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(ctrl) = "ComboBox" Then ctrl.Value = ""
Next ctrl

Call Main 'Progress Bar

lstMaster.List = Sheets("Master").Range("A4:DK" & Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
lblCount = lstMaster.ListCount
Debug.Print matchRow
End Sub
```

This code works and I'm not sure why...

```
'Delete Button
Private Sub cmbDelete_Click()
    Dim orderTable As ListObject 'Best option for reading/writing to a worksheet with a table
    Set orderTable = Worksheets("Master").ListObjects("MASTER")
    Dim Shop_Order_Number As String
    Shop_Order_Number = Trim(txtShopOrdNum)
    Dim i As String
    Dim ctrl As Variant
    Dim answer As Integer
        answer = MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbYesNo + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2, "Delete this order")
            If answer = vbYes Then
            MsgBox ("Shop Order deleted.")
            Else
        MsgBox "Deletion canceled."
        'do nothing
            End If
    With Worksheets("Master")
            i = WorksheetFunction.Match(Shop_Order_Number, .Range("E:E"), 0)
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
    End With
    For Each ctrl In Controls  'The following code clears the textboxes'
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(ctrl) = "ComboBox" Then ctrl.Value = ""
    Next ctrl
Call Main 'Progress Bar
lstMaster.List = Sheets("Master").Range("A4:DK" & Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
lblCount = lstMaster.ListCount
Debug.Print i
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm still struggling with this code.  Can anyone assist?
If I change Dim i As Variant, then it deletes Row 1, not the row it is supposed to match.

Comment: I'm trying to fix this and have edited the code in my original post. However, despite my edits, I'm still getting the same results. This newbie could really use some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if you're not getting this because the match is not returning anything. You can't assign i if there is no match. You might be better off putting the match in an error handler. As an example:

```
Dim rng as Range
Dim rNum as long
Set rng = Worksheets("Master").Range("SHOPORDNO")
If Not IsError(Application.Match(son, rng, 0)) Then
    rNum = Application.Match(son, rng, 0)
    MsgBox rNum
Else
    MsgBox "error"
End If
```

Please note that I'm writing this directly (not in an SDE) so there might be a typo or two.

Comment: You are correct, for reasons I still don't understand, it was not returning anything. I ran the code I added to my original post through break mode and for some reason this now works. I'm still new to using this site. So, I apologize if I'm doing this incorrectly.

Comment: If I understand the current issue (deleting a row now in the area you are expecting) might I suggest it has to do with the named range. The match may be giving you an index according to the named range which you are then applying the delete using the worksheet index. Either get the index from the worksheet or do some math to get the evaluated worksheet row index or delete the row index from the named range (Range("SHOPORDNO").Rows(i).Delete or something similar.

Comment: I appreciate your insight and will make notes so I understand this moving forward. Thank you so much for your time!